# Find MPMoviePlayerController is Playing Or not

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to find the MPMovieplayerController is playing or not with condition.

Check the Condition button click event....!

Any one help with me us....!

Thanks....!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

MPMovieplayerController is having playbackState property. On button click event you can do like

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    if(yourMoviePlayerObject.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
        NSLog(@"Yes Playing");
    else
        NSLog(@"Not Playing");
}
```

Comment: **Note** the common solution is to register for a change within the playback state instead for detecting it (see the documentation on the  MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange notification).

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/playbackState)